# View summary of actions completed today in Trello

Tags: trello

If I have a list of things I want to get done, it would be nice at the end of the day/week to go to a view that had everything completed that day/week.

In an example day, the following might happen

```
To Do    Doing    Done
-----    -----    ----
1-A   -> 1-A   -> 1-A
1-B   -> 1-B
1-C
2-A   -> 2-A   -> 2-A
```

And I'd like to be able to see that in a simple list or report. Obviously, this feature becomes much more useful when the cards moved are greater than just a few (say, 10-15).

Is there a way to accomplish this, even using some special query?

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool called reportsfortrello.com. It is free to see the last 1000 actions per board (the trello api limit).

There are 3 types of time tracking available by simply using whatever Trello client you like (phone/tab/desktop). The list tracking shows how long a card was in a “doing” list ( or whatever list you want to track). The membership tracking shows how long a person had a card membership. The third tracking option combines the two and tracks how long a person had a membership while a card was in a certain list. This method allows for people to be assigned cards in a “to-do” list and only track the time while the card was dragged into the “doing” list. You can run a report any one of these ways whenever you want.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if it will do exactly what you are looking for, but you can try [www.trellotimeline.com](http://www.trellotimeline.com/).

Comment: If you are affiliated with the site, please disclose that in your answer.